# How to check if array is sorted either ascending or descending?

Tags: c, arrays

What I have is a function that checks the array and provides output based on whether it is sorted or not.

To use that function called **my_is_sort()** I've created additional function that would sort the array for me in both ascending and descending orders:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    int size;
    int* array;
} integer_array; //structure of integer array

integer_array* ascendingSortedArray(integer_array* param_1){ //function that sorts array in asc. order

    integer_array* minToMax = param_1;

    int arrLen = param_1->size;

    for (int i = 0; i < arrLen; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < arrLen; j++){
            if (param_1->array[j] >= param_1->array[i]){
                int temp = minToMax->array[i];         
                minToMax->array[i] = minToMax->array[j];            
                minToMax->array[j] = temp;             
            }  
        }
    }

    return minToMax; //returning pointer to ascending array

}

integer_array* descendingSortedArray(integer_array* param_1){ //function that sorts array in desc. order

    int arrLen = param_1->size;
    integer_array* maxToMin = param_1;

    for (int i = 0; i < arrLen; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < arrLen; j++){
            if (param_1->array[j] <= param_1->array[i]){
                int temp = maxToMin->array[i];         
                maxToMin->array[i] = maxToMin->array[j];            
                maxToMin->array[j] = temp;             
            }  
        }
    }

    return maxToMin; //returning pointer to ascending array

}

int my_is_sort(integer_array* param_1) {

    integer_array* minToMaxArr = ascendingSortedArray(param_1);
    integer_array* maxToMinArr = descendingSortedArray(param_1);

    for(int i=0; i<param_1->size; i++){
        if(param_1->array[i]!=minToMaxArr->array[i] && param_1->array[i]!=maxToMinArr->array[param_1->size-i-1]){
            return 0; //checking if element at index i is same as the ith element of ascending array or (arrayLen-i-1)the element of descending array. E.g. if 1st element of passed array is not as same as 1st element of asc. array and last element of desc. array, it returns 0
        }
    }

    return 1;

}
```

Then to test it I've passed some arrays into my function. For example, firstly I did pass **[1,1,2]** the function returned **1** (which is right), when I passed **[-2,-1,1]** it returned **1** again (which is right). But then I passed **[4, 7, 0, 3]**, and output was 1 although it had to be 0 since passed array is not sorted in either order. What is the source of the problem?

Here's the failing testing case in **main()**:

```
int main(){

    int arr[] = {4, 7, 0, 3};
    integer_array* result = malloc(sizeof(integer_array));

    result->array = arr;
    result->size = 4;

    int sorted = my_is_sort(result);

    printf("%i\n", sorted);
}
```

Comment: Don't confuse arrays and pointers. I suggest reading section 6 of the [comp.lang.c faq](http://c-faq.com/).

Comment: `ascendingSortedArray(param_1); descendingSortedArray(param_1);`. Those functions are operating on the same array and then you compare the same array once more. That is, you only ever have one array whereas it appears you think you have three seperate arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do something along the lines of

```
bool IsSorted(int[] a, int size)
{
  if (size < 3)
    return true;
  int state = 0; // 0 = unknown, 1 = asc, 2 = desc
  int p = a[0];
  for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
  {
    int x = a[i];
    if (p < x)
    {
      switch(state)
      {
        case: 0: state = 1; break;
        case  2: return false;
      }
    } else if (p > x)
    {
      switch(state)
      {
        case: 0: state = 2; break;
        case  1: return false;
      }
      p = x;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's gonna help you but my tests showed that in function `my_is_sort` every `integer_array*` is descending (`param_1`,`minToMaxArr`,`maxToMinArr`) and that's why everything is 1, but I cannot really tell why.